# htaccess redirection rule based on query string

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2

I have dynamic resizing service running on /index.php file and it will create processed (resized,optimised) file on /media/_cache folder appending query parameters value like:

http://mymedia.service.com/content/2018/Apr/filename.jpg?**w=200&h=200&cc=1**

it will create a file under:
/media/_cache/content/2018/Apr/**filename_w200_h200_cc.jpg**

Here I need a htaccess rule to verify if the file already exists then it should server directly from the server without going to /index.php page.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

After a long efforts, finally I found a way to do so:

```
#when url has width and height params only
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/media
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^w=(\d+)&h=(\d+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(\w+)$ /media/_cache/$1_w%1_h%2.$2   [L]

#when url has width, height and cc
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/media
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^w=(\d+)&h=(\d+)&cc=1$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(\w+)$ /media/_cache/$1_w%1_h%2_cc.$2    [L]

#if redirection rule not found file in cache, then it will be redirect to index.php for resizing & optimization
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1
```